# How do I debug a crash of the desktop environment caused by Chromium?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

There is some line of JavaScript that is causing my desktop environment on Linux to crash entirely, bringing me to the login screen. I can reliably trigger the crash in Chrome but I don't know which exact lines are causing it.

The site is shellshock.io (a game) and pressing escape while on the map causes the crash. I've tried to enter debug mode and track it line by line but there's a lot of code so I don't know where to start.

Is there any way to tell chrome to log each line of JS executed up until it crashes?

I've turned on logging based on https://superuser.com/questions/607563/how-to-determine-what-is-causing-chrome-to-show-the-aw-snap-dialogue#1007777 and the logs end at a console.log, meaning that the crash didn't log anything useful. It may also be that the crash, although triggered by Chrome, is actually from elsewhere and thus kills Chrome before it can report a crash.

I cannot reproduce the issue on Firefox. It has been reproduced with both Ungoogled Chromium via Flatpak and Chromium via rpm.

Comment: Nothing in the JavaScript should be able to log you out of your desktop environment, unless you've installed an extension that permits this. Does this still happen if you disable all your browser extensions?

Comment: I have no extensions installed. It's likely a bug as the whole desktop crashes

Comment: [unix.se] would probably be a better place to ask about this.